# How detect template page with JS Vanilla in WordPress editor (FSE)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I would like to get the FSE template page (and others datas) after Gutemberg is loaded. I did this but not work. It's return undefined. You have an idea ?

Thanks

**in functions.php**

```php
function editor_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'script-slug',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/to/my/script.js',
        array('wp-dom', 'wp-data'),
        '1.0.0',
        true,
    );
}
add_action('enqueue_block_assets', 'editor_scripts', 10, 1);
```

**in script.js**

```js
wp.domReady(() => {
  const template = wp.data.select("core/block-editor").getTemplate();
  console.log(template);
}
```